# Magento2 Getting error while downloading module via composer

Tags: magento2, module

Magento2 I have created a custom module & uploaded on package list so that anyone can download the module via composer. For downloading the module we are using the following command.

> sudo composer require cuspay/exetension:dev-main

We are getting following error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                 
  Could not find package cuspay/exetension.  
                                             
  Did you mean this?                         
      cuspay/exetension
```

Can some one guide ma on what could be the issue? It would be a great help, thanks

Comment: Did you checked this package exists on packagist? Also can you please share packagist url.

Comment: @RahulBarot https://packagist.org/packages/cuspay/exetension

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/cuspay/exetension

Answer (score 1):

Please check following points:

- Do not use `sudo` with composer
- Use composer 2 instead of composer 1 **(This package is not installable via Composer 1.x)**
- Remove `"require": { "bharat2533/cuspayextension": "dev-main"}"` from your composer.json file as it does not exist.
- After remove `require`, update package in https://packagist.org/

Hope Above will help!

Comment: Sadly stilll not working after making changes

Comment: can you confirm you are using composer 2 ? I am able to install your module! you check number of install on your packagist. it is showing 1

Comment: I m getting error while installing in version 2. Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/composer-root-update-plugin is locked to version 1.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - magento/composer-root-update-plugin 1.0.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 2
    - dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer is locked to version v0.5.0 and an update of this package was not requested.

Comment: Can u let me know cmd u used?

Comment: I installed it in separate directory not in magento. it seems magento 2 still need composer 1 while your module need composer 2. keep global composer to magento 1 and use composer 2 using `composer.phar` file!.

Comment: sudo composer config repositories.cuspayextension vcs https://github.com/bharat2533/cuspayextension.git

Comment: This way I was able 2 in composer 1, it is right?

Comment: 1 - create directory i.e composer2
2 - inside directory run following command
3 - php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
4 - php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
5- php composer-setup.php
6 - php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
7 - in magento 2 root run `php /pat/to/composer.phar require cuspay/exetension

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127664/discussion-between-pawan-and-arjun).

Comment: did you successfully installed ?

Comment: Yes I was able to isntall successfully in composer1 by making changes in composer.json

Comment: great... composer.json of magento 2 Or module ?

Comment: module, composer 2 still needs to be download as you mentioned in some other directory & not magento2